# cannot recognize input near '>' ',' 'COUNT' in selection target Command exiting with ret '64'

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute the query below:

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '${OUTPUT}/os_requests/' SELECT OS, ‘—>’, COUNT(*) FROM cloudfront_logs WHERE DateLog BETWEEN '2014-07-05' AND '2014-08-05' GROUP BY OS;

But i am getting this error:

FAILED: ParseException line 3:104 cannot recognize input near '>' ',' 'COUNT' in selection target Command exiting with ret '64'

returned every time that looks like this. I have the file saved as a .q file.

Comment: Have you tried removing '->' from your SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

Pls use single quote (`'`). Below SQL will work. Your sql has back quote(`‘`) which wont work in sql.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '${OUTPUT}/os_requests/' SELECT OS, '—>', COUNT(*) FROM cloudfront_logs WHERE DateLog BETWEEN '2014-07-05' AND '2014-08-05' GROUP BY OS;
```

[image]